# Receiving Kurento Media Server stream in Android WebView

Tags: android, video-streaming, webrtc, kurento

I am trying the Kurento *one to many* video call example ([this one](https://www.kurento.org/docs/5.1.1/tutorials/node/tutorial-3-one2many.html)) where a Raspberry Pi sends a stream to the KMS using uv4l. I am trying to view the stream on an Android app using a WebView. I used a custom WebViewClient to avoid the SSL certificate error. However, when the hardware acceleration is enabled, a green rectangle is displayed instead of the video, and when the acceleration is disabled, a spinning wheel is displayed. However, the audio is received correctly.

Logcat displays the following messages:

> [WARNING:webrtcsession.cc(1719)] Candidate has unknown component: Cand[1:2:udp:2013266430:IP:PORT:local::0::] for content: audio
>
> [WARNING:srtpfilter.cc(585)] Failed to unprotect SRTP packet, err=9
>
> [ERROR:channel.cc(666)] Failed to unprotect video RTP packet:
> size=1133, seqnum=23250, SSRC=1884862060

The code I use for the WebView is the following.

```
    WebView displayWebView = (WebView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.displayWebView);
    WebSettings webSettings = displayWebView.getSettings();
    webSettings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
    webSettings.setUseWideViewPort(true);
    webSettings.setLoadWithOverviewMode(true);

    displayWebView.setWebViewClient(new CustomWebViewClient());

    displayWebView.loadUrl("https://IP:PORT/");
```

The code for CustomWebViewClient is the following.

```
private class CustomWebViewClient extends WebViewClient {

    @Override
    public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
        view.loadUrl(url);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public void onReceivedSslError(WebView view, SslErrorHandler handler, SslError error) {
        Log.d(TAG, "Ignoring SSL certificate error...");
        handler.proceed();
    }
}
```

I tested the app on phones running Lollipop. I guess it is something related to the WebView. Any help?

Comment: Did you found a solution? I'm trying to solve the same problem.

Answer (score 0):

The officially supported way of working with WebRTC is using [WebRTC-capable browsers](http://caniuse.com/#feat=rtcpeerconnection) (i.e. Chrome, Firefox and Opera, and Android Browser). WebView does indeed support WebRTC (though [not everything](https://developer.chrome.com/multidevice/webview/overview#does_the_new_webview_have_feature_parity_with_chrome_for_android_)), but how to get WebRTC working in WebView is something that will be better answered by WebView users.

On the other hand, doing [some research it seems like Crosswalk is a better option](https://webrtchacks.com/webrtc-hybrid-applications/), as it embeds a fully functional Chrome browser.